# AsmComponentsModule does not have exported components

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Our team needs to add custom code to the ASM module in order to make SSO login possible in our project, and we realised the `AsmComponentsModule` doesn't export its declared components. This made it difficult for us to reuse them, since we had to create our own custom module which is a copy of `AsmComponentsModule`, containing components that are simply extensions of the components declared on it.

This is problematic, since we also had to duplicate HTML and SCSS files. The problem would be even bigger if this module had even more components declared on it.

Is there a better way to do this? Or we should expect a future fix containing the `exports` array on this module?

Answer (score 2):

PR Fix: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/15282

Will be released into 4.3.1 and 3.4.7 patches.